# Does anybody have a source for epoxy putty (for plastics) in black color?

Tags: plumbing, shower, bathtub, adhesive, plumbing-fixture

I need to seal a broken plastic ring, but it needs to stay black - all the epoxy putties I find are grey or white. Thanx!

Comment: Down voting because this is a [shop for me](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/607/can-we-discourage-shop-for-me-type-questions) question. It's borderline whether it should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this one some time ago, it stayed black and worked well on a plastic planter

[http://www.amazon.com/Anderson-Epoxy-Putty-Black-9908K/dp/B004DF5MEC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004DF5MEC)

Answer (score -1):

McMaster-Carr is like a real-life version of the Acme company in roadrunner cartoons, you can get just about anything from them when the local hardware store doesn't have the right stuff.

http://www.mcmaster.com/#general-purpose-epoxy-adhesives/=k82ujl